# SignalR remote desktop control with bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, optimization, signalr

I have a question that is related to the optimization of speed streaming.
I have 2 types of projects. The first one is the Desktop app (WindowsForms). The Other one is Web Application (Asp.Net Core MVC).

1. Desktop app features: This application should be a remote desktop server which I bitmap desktop screen in while true and invoke signalR method in web side and pass to signalR as base64.

   ```
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
        var thread = new Thread(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                Rectangle bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                ImageCodecInfo pngEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder,
                    0L);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
                Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bound.Width, bound.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(bound.X, bound.Y, 0, 0, bound.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceErase);

                string sigBase64 = null;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    screenshot.Save(ms, pngEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                    sigBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync("Image", sigBase64);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(150);
                GC.Collect();
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
   ```
2. Web side app features: there is signalR hub that is receiving base64 from the desktop side in every milli second and broadcast it to the front-end.

   ```
    public async Task Image(string base64)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ViewImage", base64);
    }
   ```

Javascript Side:

```
<div class="text-center">
   <canvas id="received" width="1200" height="800" style="border: solid 1px black"></canvas>
</div>

 connection.on("ViewImage", function (base64) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('received');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let source = "data:image/png;base64, " + base64;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = source;
    img.onload = function ()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});
```

I think everything is clear now. So, I have a problem that is related to optimization. Everything is working well in my local machine and local network. But when I deploy the web project to any publish server, it will be freeze and slow. How can I optimize this problem? Do you know any way to replace base64 with another analogue?

Comment: Scale down the images.... ?

Comment: Also the use of the Thread class and Sleep seems to be misplaced , the fact that you have to use `GC.Collect();` seems problematic and likely because you are not disposing anything and leaking resources left right and center

Comment: @TheGeneral What do you mean? I should remove thread sleep and thread class from this code? and I should use their GC.Collect() ? or other. Could you please more details?